# How to flush I/O buffer in coprocess's pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe, flush

I am using *pipe* to write a coprocess. The parent creates two pipes, one pipe for write to the child and the other for read from child. But when I run the program, it is pending because it sets the *printf* to fully buffered as default. And I don't want to *fflush* the buffer in the child process source code.

I know the Chapter 19 in *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* introduced a way using pseudo-terminal. But I want to know if there is a more sample way to do it. Thanks to all.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main()
{
    #define MAXSIZE 1024

    char workload[MAXSIZE];
    char result[MAXSIZE];
    char buf[10] = {0};
    workload[strlen(workload)] = EOF;
    int workload_size = strlen(workload);

    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    int n;
    pid_t pid;
    if (pipe(fd1) < 0 || pipe(fd2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        while(fgets(workload, MAXSIZE, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            workload_size = strlen(workload);
            if (write(fd1[1], workload, workload_size) != workload_size) {
                fprintf(stderr, "write to pipe error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }

            if ((n = read(fd2[0], result, MAXSIZE)) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read from pipe error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }

            if (n == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "child closed the pipe\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            result[n] = 0;

            if (puts(result) == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "fputs error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        if (fd1[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
            if (dup2(fd1[0] ,STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO) {
                fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdin.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(fd1[0]);
        }
        if (fd2[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            if (dup2(fd2[1] ,STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO) {
                fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdout.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(fd2[1]);
        }

        if (execl("./a.out", "a.out", NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "execl error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The child process just read from standard input and output it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    #define MAXSIZE 1024
    char x[MAXSIZE];
    int n;
    while(fgets(x, 1024, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) utility to change the buffering of your child process.

Or, if you can change the code of the child process, call [`setvbuf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/setvbuf.html) directly from the child process.

Comment: And I'm wonder if I could change the buffering of pipe directly in the source code?

Comment: I tried to use setvbuf to set the child process's buffer. But it did not work. I add these code before execl: setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);

Comment: That won't work before `execl`. `setvbuf` needs to be called from the child process.

Comment: Thanks. Then I will use stdbuf because I don't want to change the source code of the child process.

Comment: And what if I use setvbuf to set the pipe's buffer? I tried to open pipe as stream using fdopen, but it failed: Bad file descriptor. Is it possible to set it in the parent process?

Comment: `setvbuf` only affects a `FILE` structure, not the file descriptor/description.

Comment: `fdopen` could return a `FILE` structure and I used it in `setvbuf`. I know it is wrong now. I just googled it and think there is no sample way to do this in the parent process.